# ng-repeat, how to call two items?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying a select with ng-options. The problem is, my ng-options label is composed of two values ..

my code goes something like this

```
<select ng-model='item.batsman' ng-options='b.player.first_name b.player.last_name for b in shortlist'></select>
```

if i do, b.player.first_name .. the thing works fine, but i cannot have two values a label. what should i do?

i have tried a different method,

```
<td>
    <select ng-model='item.batsman'>
        <option ng-repeat='batsman in shortlist' value='{{ batsman.player.id }}'>
         {{ batsman.player.first_name }} {{batsman.player.last_name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</td>
```

but it doesn't let me pick a json value. my problem will be solved by picking up the json value, or by having the label as two values.

//mouse

Answer (score 2):

You can write the label expression as `b.player.first_name + " " + b.player.last_name` - like this:

```html
<select ng-model='item.batsman' ng-options='b.player.first_name + " " + b.player.last_name for b in shortlist'></select>
```

Comment: About 3 seconds faster.  Here is a demo I worked up with a recent plunker I did that does a menuname + id together to demonstrate this.  http://plnkr.co/edit/L63JJbqxj5jM1UAdPXce?p=preview